# Blooming at moonlight

Tags: botany, photosynthesis, circadian-rhythms

At the moment [a popular question in the physics SE community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645172/247642) is about [night-blooming cereus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night-blooming_cereus): this flower blooms at full moon, that is it is capable of making difference between the moonlight and sunlight.

The question has attracted a lot of guesswork, with some people even claiming that the cereus doesn't know about the moon, but simply blooms at night - [the blooming at full moon however seems to find experimental confirmation](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27030087/). It is thus more plausible that the flower distingushes between the light intensities of the moonlight and the sunlight, [as suggested here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27019304/).

The closest question that I found in this forum [is about flowers open during the daytime and closed at night (or vice versa)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/9747/59521). I suppose one could construct a more sophisticated model based on the mechanisms described here, but I would appreciate an expert answer.

To restate the question:
*How does night-blooming cereus distinguish between moonlight and sunlight?*

Comment: I'd really like to get an expert answer to this interesting question. Would you consider offering a bounty?